# Insert line at start of file with Ansible

Tags: ansible

You can insert a line at the end of a file or before/after some regex with [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/lineinfile_module.html). But how do I insert a line at the start of a file?

Answer (score 15):

From [the link to the module manual you included in the question](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/lineinfile_module.html):

> `insertbefore`　　Used with `state=present`. If specified, the line will be inserted before the last match of specified regular expression. A value is available; **`BOF` for inserting the line at the beginning of the file**. If specified regular expression has no matches, the line will be inserted at the end of the file. May not be used with `backrefs`.

So:

```
- lineinfile:
    path: path/to/file
    insertbefore: BOF
    line: my_line
```